# International Student From Canada travelling to South America with USA Layover (With B2 visa and trip to USA with I-192 form)

Tags: air-travel, usa, transit, luggage, pakistani-citizens

I am an international graduate student living in Toronto. In two weeks, I am travelling to Peru to attend my friend's wedding. I will be taking the American Airline and transiting through Miami while going to Lima and Dallas while coming back to Toronto. My transit time is 1.5 to 2 hours. Previously, I have traveled to USA for the first time from Buffalo via Niagara Border last October. I have a B2 visa and a valid I-192 card.

My questions are:

1. I know I have to go through Border security at Miami when I arrive to connect my fight to Lima but will I have go through it again in Dallas while going back to Toronto? My concern is the layover time, which is so short and immigration lines could be huge.
2. Is there a facility for luggage transfer or I have reclaim it at both the stopovers? My airline is same throughout. Don't want to miss flights.
3. Finally can I return my I-192 when leaving Dallas to Toronto? Just for my own convenience? They ask you to post it or hand it over and since I will be in USA, I might as well return it.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify your itinerary?  Is it Lima->Miami->Dallas->Toronto?

Comment: (Departure)Toronto-Miami (transit)-Lima (Arrival)           (Departure)Lima-Dallas (Transit)-Toronto (Arrival)

Comment: And what about coming back?

Comment: @RobHoare It's [I-192](http://www.uscis.gov/i-192)

Comment: Your are correct...just checked my passport...it is 1-94 entry permit (while colour card)

Comment: To Karlson: I am going from Toronto to Miami, where I have a 2 hr stopover then taking a flight to Lima.  Coming back I am taking my flight from Lima to Dallas (1.5 hr stopover) and coming back to Toronto.

Comment: Last Question: What's your citizenship?

Comment: I am from Pakistan. Hope this is not a problem. Getting the USA visa was smooth (maybe because I am a woman and have multiple visas) but this transit route in USA and going through the immigration process in just might result in flight delays so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 5):

First things first there is a lot of related questions regarding [Transiting through the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit+usa) so you might look through those for more information.

With that out of the way:

On your way to Lima you will be passing US immigration and [Customs in Toronto](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23335/us-customs-when-coming-through-canada), so your I-94 will be collected there.  Once you arrive in Miami your luggage will be transferred to flight to Lima if your itinerary is the same.

Your trip back will be a little different you will be passing immigration in Dallas when you arrive and then another in Canada when you arrive in Toronto.

Since there is no international transit zones in US airports you will have to go through immigration, collect your luggage recheck it for the [destination flight](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k1632073-Connecting_flights_in_Dallas_Fort_Worth-Air_Travel.html) and go to the [appropriate terminal](https://dfwairport.com/connect/index.php) to catch your flight.

The minimum connection time set by [American Airlines](http://www.flyerguide.com/wiki/index.php/Minimum_Connecting_Times_(AA)), which given your connection points is your airline I assume, suggest 1 hour and 10 minutes minimum, so 1.5 hours is cutting it close but should be possible.

Returning your I-94 that you have just received in Dallas should be possible but may not be necessary.

Comment: @internationalstudent If this answers all your questions, you might want to “accept” the answer by clicking the little checkmark on the left!